"Cannot find EventEmitter for receivedTouches" when using a RecyclerView inside a React native UI Component
I have a React native UI Component that uses a RecyclerView to display a scrollable list of Cards.
I define my View like this:
public class ListView extends LinearLayout {
    CustomRecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    Product[] products;

    public ListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.list, this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void setData(@Nullable ReadableArray data) {
        post(() -> {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            assert data != null;
            products = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), Product[].class);
            adapter.clearProducts();
            adapter.addProducts(Arrays.asList(products));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
    }
}

and my Manager like this:
public class ListViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<ListView> {
    private final String REACT_CLASS = "nativeList";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListView createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new ListView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "data")
    public void setData(ListView view, ReadableArray data) {
        view.setData(data);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "refreshing")
    public void setRefreshing(ListView view, boolean refreshing) {
        view.setRefreshing(refreshing);
    }
}

My list is properly displayed but when I interact with the cards, I receive a lot of errors like this:
E  Unhandled SoftException
                 com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactNoCrashSoftException: Cannot find EventEmitter for receivedTouches: ReactTag[26] UIManagerType[2] EventName[topTouchMove]
                    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.ReactEventEmitter.receiveTouches(ReactEventEmitter.java:103)
                    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.TouchEvent.dispatchModern(TouchEvent.java:192)
                    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl$DispatchEventsRunnable.run(EventDispatcherImpl.java:370)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:234)

It seems that ReactNative is not aware of the views inside the RecyclerView. So when I interact with them, ReactNative is lost and can't an associated handler on its side.
The real issue is that, sometime, ReactTag[26] corresponds to a completely different View in ReactNative DOM. React native triggers a completely unrelated handlers and it causes weird bugs on the app.
How can I make React native aware of what is inside my recyclerView ? or at least ignore it ?

I was able to kind of fix the problem. On each child of my RecyclerView, I set an Id high enough to not clash with the ones generated by React native.
It is not perfect but get rid of random clicks. It does not fix the softException Cannot find EventEmitter for receivedTouches though.
